# how to get words separated by a comma after final full stop

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get all the text after the last `.` in a string. For example,

```
const string = 'user.teams.firstWord,secondWord';
```

It will always be of pattern,

```js
x.y.wordOne,wordTwo
```

where I am looking to extract `wordOne` and `wordTwo`

In this case the result I would be looking for is `firstWord,secondWord`;

I have tried many approaches but cannot figure it out.

My latest attempt looks like

```
const [first, second] = string.split('.').pop().split(',');
```

Comment: Your code should work. Are you seeing any issue?

Comment: hahaha, and so it does. I hadn't tested it with the new string. The string previously was `userteams.firstWord,secondWord';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lastIndexOf('.');`

```
string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).split(',');
```

Answer (score 3):

Code should be fine, you can use a regular expression for the match. Plenty of ways to write it, here is one way

```js
const [match, first, second] = 'user.teams.firstWord,secondWord'.match(/\.([^.]+),(.+)$/)
console.log(first, second)
```